# Making an iPhone App not searchable on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to upload an app to AppStore and provide a link to selected users only. In other words, i want to send them the URL so they can download it, but i don't want other to be able to search for it on the App Store.

Comment: Can't be done. If you only want a few people, use Adhoc deployment.

Comment: upto some extend B2B will help if you specify it for any company, etc..read about B2B..

Comment: Not searchable by name, or by keyword?  If you use extremely common words for both, your app will be buried below 100's of other apps in the search results.

Comment: what i really want is that unless you have the URL you cannot find the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use App Store redeem codes without releasing an approved app for sale.  Unless released, it will be invisible.  However, redeem codes are limited in number, and you may not be able to update an app without releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Read about B2B or use adhoc builds for selected devices.

Comment: Ad Hoc build are too much work. i just want to send someone a URL and have them down load it.

Comment: I will check B2B. Is there a way to use redemption codes?

Comment: You distribute your apps only throw redemption codes, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: i think i will solve it on the app level by requiring users to enter an activation code.